# I need to sort a list of values based on their absolute values using the <list>.sort( key=<key> ) method in python

Tags: python, list

The function I wrote already does all the work but I can't call it using the ".sort( key= )"

```
numlist = [-10, -7, -3, -2, 0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10]

def absolute(x):
    numlist = []
    for i in x:
        if i < 0:
            p = i * -1
            numlist.append(p)
        else:
            numlist.append(i)
    numlist.sort()
    return numlist
 
numlist.sort(key=lambda x: absolute(numlist))
print(numlist)
```

Comment: Why sort twice? Just call `absolute()` with a list, it already sorts the results before returning.

Comment: this is just `numlist.sort(key=abs)` lol @AndrejKesely ... why all the extra?

Comment: The way you have it coded, it will return the same key (a list) for every item.  That's not going to be an effective sort.

Answer (score 0):

A sample code below do the job, no need for extra functions

```
import numpy as np

numlist = [-10, -7, -3, -2, 0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10]

numlist = np.abs(numlist)
numlist.sort()

print(numlist)
```